How to properly connect and do a proper topology on this manifold

I am trying to connect these together so that i get a proper mesh but I just don't know really how to. It has me stumped. I'm still a bit new to blender so any help please take your time to explain. Thanks!


Hello maybe show the object you are trying to achieve so that we propose a solution?

@moonboots my apologizes, added more images

You could simply merge the vertices, you just need to work a bit on your topology

To get a view of good practices, may I suggest to read this post: Why is my topology messed up compared to object I am trying to model? How to fix this? ? (actually by moonbooots...)

If what you show are separate meshes within the same object, you can first select a branch then Face > Intersect (Boolean), then rework the topology by meging vertices etc
